# Reset datetime-local input to original (ngModel) value in template forms

Tags: angular

My Angular 6 template form loads with the latest data.  The user can change the date/time in the datetime-local input, but I can't figure out how to reset that back to the original date/time (loaded in the ngModel from array.. "one.classTimesLogOffRevised"), if the user wants to cancel.  I can clear the date input, but whatever date value was entered before hitting the cancel button, remains and posts to the ngModel (therefore changing the date).
I removed the blue "X" that resets the date, because that was making everything null when clicked (do not want that).
Part of my challenge here is that I'm using the same ngModel, the new value overwrites the old.  But there should be a way to restore that old value ..?

I tried using markAsPristine() method, I thought should work, (again, this is a template driven form), but it resets nothing.  See my code for usage example.

```
   <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(revisedRecord)" novalidate 
 #revisedRecord="ngForm">
 <div *ngFor="let one of editOneLogIn; let in = index"> 

   <label for="name">Additional REVISED Student Check-Out Time</label>
   <p>Revised Check-Out Time: {{ one.classTimesLogOffRevised  | date: 
  'medium' }} </p>

 <div>
          <input type="hidden" [ngModel]="one.classTimesLogOffRevised | 
          date: 'medium' "
 name="classTimesLogOffRevised-{{in}}" 
 (ngModelChange)="classTimesLogOffRevised=$event"
 [ngModel]="ClassTimesLogOffRevised | date: 'medium' " 
 (ngModelChange)="ClassTimesLogOffRevised=$event"
   class="form-control">
   </div>


       <input type="datetime-local" [ngModel]="one.classTimesLogOffRevised | 
       date: 'medium' "
   (ngModelChange)="classTimesLogOffRevised=$event" 
   name="ClassTimesLogOffRevised"
   [ngModel]="ClassTimesLogOffRevised | date: 'medium' " 
   (ngModelChange)="ClassTimesLogOffRevised=$event"
   required #dateClear class="form-control">

 <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" 
 (click)="dateClear.value = one.classTimesLogOffRevised">Cancel2</button>    

 </div> </form>
```

Component.ts...

```
 import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
 import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router, ExtraOptions } from 
 '@angular/router';
 import { DataStorageService } from 'src/app/shared/data-storage.service';
 import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-teacheredit',
   templateUrl: './teacheredit.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./teacheredit.component.css']
 })
 export class TeachereditComponent implements OnInit {

   @ViewChild('revisedRecord') slForm: NgForm;
   public editOneLogIn: Array<any>;

  ngOnInit(): void {

  this.dataStorageService.getOneLogIn(id).subscribe((importOneLogIn: any) => 
  this.editOneLogIn = [importOneLogIn]);
   }

...

  cancelTimeChange() {

 // this does not reset anything in the form (no errors), does not work

 this.slForm.form.markAsPristine();
  }
```

Here is the object in the array (editOneLogIn)...

```
 classTimesLogInDate: "2019-06-06T16:30:37-05:00"
 classTimesLogInRevised: null
 classTimesLogOffDate: "2019-06-06T16:31:21-05:00"
 classTimesLogOffRevised: "2019-06-06T17:36:00-05:00"
 classTimesRevisedRecord: true
 classTimesRowId: 877
 classTimesStudentId: 568790
 classTimesTeacherId: "b14845"
 classTimesTotalTime: "01:05:23"
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, change onclick event for setting date to initial value use below option

```
(click)="dateClear.value = one.classTimesLogOffRevised"
```

code sample for reference - https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-kbw7z

Note: To set date for input with datetime-local, value should always be formatted in yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm

Refer MDN for more details on  datetime-local input -https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

Comment: Thanks so much for looking at this.  I edited my code, I actually have 2 inputs (1 hidden) needed to get the original value copied to the ngModel to post.  I tried your onclick and it clears out the value instead of inserting the original value.  I see that your codesandbox works.  Not sure why mine does not work.

Comment: Added the object and API call to my code.  Changes to the date for ngModel ClassTimesLogOffRevised overwrites the original one.classTimesLogOffRevised value.  But I can't figure out how to allow the user to cancel date edits and post the original one.classTimesLogOffRevised value -besides a cancel that reloads the whole page.  I do not know what is different about your codesandbox (that works)?  My cancel button clears the calendar, and posts the (new) time entered before clearing.   Maybe I need a function for this in the .ts file?

Comment: one best option debug is to print on html and also confirm the error or date that is getting assigned to date input?